# Setting the onClick method of a view in a Gallery disables the Gallery's fling

Tags: android, onclick, gallery, onfling

Each of the Gallery's panes hold more than a single view and I need to differentiate between their clicks  - AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() just indicates that the Gallery was clicked. What's the best way to get both Gallery flinging and view clicking simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what I needed:

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

Answer (score 0):

In your click listener, return `false`. Returning `false` means that the event was not consumed and to propagate the event to other views who may be watching the same event.

Comment: Click events cannot be intercepted because, they don't return a boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

Some part of your item layout shouldn't contain a clickable item. If you touch that part and try swiping, it should work.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't operate smoothly enough to be a workable solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But, as far as I know, this is the only way. I mean, if you have something on the gallery that's clickable, it will just be like that. It will be a bad user experience to have both click and fling at the same time, since it will confuse the user.

Comment: All I really need is to be able to differentiate a swipe from a tap - doesn't seem like this should be too difficult.